# Solid file report in SandCastle

Tags: c#, xml, documentation, documentation-generation, sandcastle

I use SandCastle for generate documentation of my C#-project.
By default I have chm-file as result of SandCastle's work.
But I want have one html-file with description of all my class. I not need navigation between parts of documentation, but I need ONE solid document with full documentation

Comment: did you find a solution since you asked the question? i would b nice to generate the documentation without the fancy javascript stuff etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, seems to that option does not exist.